# Is this elementary proof of FLT correct?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Consider the classic FLT for $n=3$, $x^3+y^3=z^3 $**

Without loss of generality,we can rewrite as $a^3+(b-a)^3=c^3…Equation (1)$

We can also assume there is no common factor between $a,b-a$ and $c …Assumption (1)$

Since $m+n$ is a factor of $m^3+n^3$, $b$ divides $c^3$.
Let $p$ be a common prime factor of $b$ and $c … Assumption (2)$

$p$ does not divide $a$ as if it did, $p$ divides $b-a$ and hence $p$ divides $a$ violating $Assumption (1)$

Rewriting Equation(1)  we get, $a^3+b^3-a^3-3b^2 a+3ba^2=c^3…Equation (2)$

rearranging we get, $b^3-c^3=3b^2 a-3ba^2 …Equation (3)$

Note that $p^3$ divides the LHS of $Equation (3)$

Two cases:

Case I: $p \ne $n
On the RHS of $Equation (3)$, $p^2$ divides the first term $3b^2 a$ but not $3ba^2$

Case II: $p = $n
Now $p^3$ divides $3b^2a$ but not $3ba^2$.

In both cases, LHS of $Equation (3) \ne RHS $

**The General case of FLT for any odd prime n:**

Without loss of generality,we can rewrite FLT as $a^n+(b-a)^n=c^n…Equation (4)$

Expanding, we get
$a^n+b^n-nC_1 b^{n-1} a+nC_2 b^{n-2} a^2-⋯-nC_{n-2} b^2 a^{n-2}+nC_{n-1} ba^{n-1}-a^n=c^n…Equation (5)$

rearranging we get,
$b^n-c^n=nC_1 b^{n-1} a- nC_2 b^{n-2} a^2+ ⋯+nC_{n-2} b^2 a^{n-2}-nC_{n-1} ba^{n-1}…Equation (6)$

Therefore $p^n$  divides the LHS of $Equation (6)$

Two cases.Case I: $p \ne n$

On RHS of Equation (6), $p^2$ divides all the terms except the last term $nC_{n-1} ba^{n-1}$

Case II: $p=n$

Now $p^3$ divides all terms of RHS except the last term $nC_{n-1} ba^{n-1}$

In both cases, LHS of $Equation (6) \ne RHS $

Comment: Something wrong *must* be there in your $n=3$ proof, otherwise the usual proof of that case, which is in fact a bit involved, would not have appeared in the history of FLT. [Sorry I didn't find exactly what your error is ...]

Answer (score 3):

The proof is incorrect. The error is in the statement
$$``\text{$p^2$ divides the first term $3b^{2}a$ but not $3a^{2}b$}."$$

In case 1, when $p$ is different than $3$, you know that $p \nmid a$, $p \nmid 3$, and $p\mid b$. But, you do not know that $p^{2} \nmid b$. This is because you chose $p$ to be any prime factor of $b$ and $c$ (assumption 2), which does not exclude the possibility that $p^{2} \mid b$.

So, if $p^{2} \mid b$, then the claim that $p^{2} \nmid 3a^{2}b$ is false, and the conclusion no longer follows.

Comment: agree... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.  What makes you think $b$ and $c$ have to have a common prime factor?

Comment: If $b \neq 1$, then you could just take $p$ to be the smallest prime factor of $b$, and then $p \mid c$. And, the case $b = 1$ is easily dispatched, since $b \geq a > 0$.

Comment: That comes from the previous line: "*$b$ divides $c^3$*".

Comment: Since you do only algebraic computations in a UFD, your proof is CERTAINLY wrong, even for the exponent 3. No need to check anything, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590336/300700 .