# On elementary proofs of Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

I came across [this one](https://sites.google.com/site/mcpogorspace/home/proof-of-the-fermat-s-last-theorem) of many claimed elementary proofs of FLT. It looked credible, and I felt surprised seeing that it wasn't drawing much attention from anyone. I investigated and I ended up finding [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590336/430906) ruling out any chances for this kind of "proofs" to be correct. Now, my question shall be organized in three steps:

- I have a very basic understanding of the "trick". I get its underlying logic, but unluckily I have a ridiculous knowledge of rings and fields, and in particular I know almost nothing of $p$-adic numbers. Can you confirm that, reasoning in analogy with the familiar number sets, I can safely assume that having a solution in $Q_p$ would imply a counterpart in $Z_p$? Is there a way to make it comprehensible how a solution made of $p$-adic integers would look like?
- This is what I'm interested in most. Is it possible to understand, at least at an intuitive level, in lay-person's terms, what is the characteristic of the ring of familiar integers that makes it different from other factorial rings? In other words, what is (or are) the features typical only of our beloved usual numbers that make FLT hold for them? In further other words, what properties have been involved by the advanced mathematical tools used to prove FLT?
- Finally, if we can spot such a characteristic, and it necessarily requires the use of instruments that Fermat didn't have, isn't this definitive evidence that Fermat *could not* have a proof? Why is this still sometimes questioned? Did he have any chance to perform something that did not fall under the disproof of the "trick", something that wouldn't apply to other rings like that of $p$-adic integers?

Comment: "having a solution in $Q_p$ would imply a counterpart in $Z_p$": yes, this is true, because one can "clear denominators" (in this case, multiply by an appropriate power of $p$) in $Q_p$ just as one can in $Q$ itself.

Comment: Another property of $\mathbb Z$ that is not true in $\mathbb Z_p$ is the infinitude of primes. There is essentially on one prime in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Oohh, so chances are that Krasner's trick isn't reliable? (I didn't find much googling it, I think that the book "Krasner versus Fermat" might be the reference) If this is the case, can I again accept the idea that an elementary proof of FLT might one day be found?

Comment: Fermat had a lot of techniques other than the ones listed. Some mathematicians think he might have presumed that a certain number field was a unique factorization domain. That is far more than the what Krasner is saying. Quote: "Elementary" means precisely that the proof uses only addition and multiplication (operations in a ring), and perhaps also the existence and unicity of decomposition into prime factors (so the ring in question is factorial)."

Comment: Just out of curiosity, @Greg, why the edit? English is not my native language, but layman googles about ten times than layperson

Comment: @Thomas In fact Krasner wasn't talking about Fermat, but about someone's "elementary" attempt. I wondered whether Fermat might have something more advanced allowing him to avoid Kresner's guillotine

Comment: My motivation is that "layman" is gender-specific, while "layperson" is gender-neutral and thus more inclusive.

Comment: I once read that some 19th century mathematician had a form-letter for replies to amateurs' attempts that he received : "Your attempt to prove FLT has as error on page ____, on line ____."

Comment: Fermat tried to use the method described on [page 7 of this article](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/real.pdf), but he didn't complete it.

Comment: Oh, and I heard that the entry in Bachet's edition of Diophantus concerning the equation $x^n + y^n = z^n$ was made by Fermat's wife.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the claim of that thread is blatantly overstated. For one thing, there are lots of properties that $\mathbb{Z}$ has, but $Z_p$ does not have. First and foremost, well ordering of the positive elements, which is heavily used as a key to solving many diophantine equations.

Now consider Fermat's elementary proof that
$$x^4 + y^4 = z^4$$ 
has no solutions for $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $xyz \ne 0$.

I'm not sure whether or not there is a solution in $p$-adic integers, for some prime $p$, but if such solutions exist, it's an example showing that the existence of qualifying $p$-adic solutions doesn't imply the existence of qualifying integer solutions.

As I indicated in the comments, I suspect that most flawed attempts, at least the ones where the solver knows some Number Theory and is not obviously crazy, would include steps for which there is no analogue in $Z_p$, so the $Z_p$ criterion would be useless for invalidating those attempts.

For a given proposed proof, a more common way of quickly demonstrating that there must be a mistake$\,-\,$without actually pinpointing the error, is to observe that the argument would still work for the equation $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, or, alternatively, to apply the argument line by line for the equation $x^3+y^3=z^3$, and see if the proof at least works for that case.

Comment: I don't think that argument is overstated, it is just hard to understand if you don't read carefully. Basically, he's just saying, "If the argument would work in $\mathbb Z_p$, it doesn't work." It doesn't mean (or say) there is no elementary proof, except for a very specific (and spelled out) definition of "elementary."

Comment: I read it as: if the argument _doesn't_ work in $Z_p$, then it _doesn't_ work in $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, if one can show that there are solutions in $Z_p$, then supposedly that implies that there's no elementary proof of the non-existence of solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$. The overreach is the restriction as to what qualifies as "elementary".

Comment: Arguments such as "consider the least positive integer such that ..." are not part of what that thread views as "elementary". But elementary diophantine arguments make free use of that principle.

Comment: I think you two are saying the same thing from two different points of view. I think that the safest expression is: "if an argument, reportedlly proving FLT in $\mathbb Z$ can be applied unchanged in $Z_p$, given that we know that FLT in $Z_p$ fails, must contain a mistake"

Comment: Sure, but my sense is that criterion would filter out very few non-gibberish flawed attempts, if any. In other words, I would expect that a serious, but flawed attempt, would likely make use of well-ordering, as well as other properties of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ which have no analogue in $Z_p$.

Comment: You haven't dealt with a lot of amateur mathematicians, have you? A lot of people without math sophistication try to solve Fermat. While most people with math knowledge won't make these sorts of errors, the vast majority of "proofs" of Fermat are by unsophisticated amateurs.

Comment: Actually, I have dealt with many such amateurs. and have seen many flawed elementary proofs of FLT. I haven't seen even one such proof, (ignoring the ones by obvious total cranks), which would be disproved by the $p$-adic interpretation in the linked question.

Comment: However many such proposed proofs can be invalidated by the much more elementary attack I mentioned in my post: How does the proposed proof specialize to the cases $n=2$ or $n=3$?

Comment: Your answer is very close to addressing all my concerns. One doubt still alive: is it possible that well-ordering is implicitly used by proof attempts that look readable to a non-pro mathematician? For example the one I mention at the beginning, for which I have added a link. The underlying question is: is it obvious to distinguish if such an attempt "includes steps for which there is no analogue in $Z_p$"?

Comment: The $Z_p$ criterion for "elementary" is so restrictive language-wise, that there's essentially no chance that the example FLT proofs you linked to qualify. As soon as you see inequalities on elements, there's already no translation.

Comment: That's what I wanted to read, that makes your answer what I was looking for. Even if now I'm brought back wondering why no-one tries to disproove Pogorsky's attempt...

Comment: When I get a chance, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: A new "elementary proof" of FLT has been recently posted on arXiv  https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1704/1704.06335.pdf

Comment: @user1551  What link ?  The arXiv "elementary proof" ?

Comment: @nguyenquangdo Yes, arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1704/1704.06335.pdf isn't found on server.

Comment: @user1551  Ah, I wasn't aware of that. It seems it was replaced by this new version  arXiv:submit/2190304 [math.GM] 11 Mar 2018

Answer (score 1):

The last theorem of Fermat, due to the efforts of lay people, has the stigma of a perpetual motion machine. But we remember that the same stamp had a meteorite theme ...

A serious mathematician will seriously think before publishing a proof for the general case. But to enter the topic and come up with an elementary proof for the case $ n = 3 $ is an excellent warm-up for the brain with non-zero chances of success.