# An Engineer sets out to Prove Fermat's Last Theorem ...

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

This started off as a joke [post](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1970492222994635/?multi_permalinks=2208324815878040&comment_id=2208329942544194&notif_id=1550708216040412&notif_t=feedback_reaction_generic) of mine on a Facebook Group called "[Bad Maths that Gives the Right Answer](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1970492222994635/)", in which I pulled a Fermat and claimed that the last bit of the proof was too long to post. But the "proof" that I posted raised some questions that intrigued me, so I will repost it here and then raise my questions. Here we go ...

I will start with the supposition that Fermat’s celebrated conjecture is false i.e., that there do in fact exist non-zero integer values of  $x$, $y$, $z$ , and $n>2$ such that

$$x^n+y^n=z^n$$

The degenerate case of  $y=x$ will be ignored, since $2^{1/n}$ is irrational for $n>1$ , proving the conjecture for this trivial instance. Accordingly, since the ordering of $x$ and $y$ above is arbitrary, the fraction  $r=y/x$ which is by definition rational, can be constrained to $0<r<1$ . Substitution into the supposition above, leads to

$$\frac{x}{z}=(1+r^n)^{-\frac{1}{n}}$$

The LHS is (again, by definition) rational. Proof of Fermat’s conjecture therefore, requires proving that the RHS cannot be rational for $n>2$, for any  $r\in \mathbb{Q}$. With the Generalised Binomial Theorem, we have

$$
(1+r^n)^{-\frac{1}{n}}
=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {{-n^{-1}}\choose{k}}r^{kn}
=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-n^{-1})_k}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^{kn}r
$$

which converges absolutely, since $|r|<1$ ($y\neq x$), and the Pochhammer Symbol for the Binomial Coefficient is

$$(-n^{-1})_k=-n^{-1}(-n^{-1}-1)(-n^{-1}-2)\cdots(-n^{-1}-k+1)$$

Note that for finite $k$ , each term of the series is a finite product of rationals and hence rational. However, if it can be proved that in the limit $k\rightarrow \infty$, the product of the infinite products always yields an irrational number for $n>2$ and $r\in \mathbb{Q}$, then Fermat’s conjecture is at once proved. Moreover, even if this were not the case, the falsity of the conjecture would still require showing that the infinite sum of rationals provably converges to a rational. For $n=2$, there are at least *some* rational values of $r$ corresponding to the Pythagorean triples, for which the infinite sum does apparently converge to a rational number. Formal proof of Fermat’s conjecture for  therefore, requires demonstrating that there are *no* rational values of $r$ for which this is the case.

I will resist the juvenile urge to “Pull a Fermat” again, and claim that I have a proof that is too large to fit here, and instead readily concede that such a proof is well above my capabilities as a lowly engineer. I do have the following questions, however:

1) Is this a viable approach?

2) Has something along these lines been attempted by Number Theorists before?

3) Can a form of the Thue-Siegel-Roth Theorem be used to determine the convergence to a rational/irrational?

I thank you for your indulgence!

Comment: Well, it's beyond my ability (and everyone here's I bet) and I hate to appeal to authority but the fact that approaches such as this *failed* for over THREE HUNDRED YEARS by people much smarter than you or I will ever be, I'd say,  that although I can't say it's not viable I really, really doubt it is.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you're correct, although it seemed (at least to me) as a logical starting point, but a fairly extensive search yielded nothing along these lines!

Comment: Since $n(-1)^k(-n^{-1})_k=\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(i+n^{-1})\in [(k-1)!,\,k!]$, your $k$th term's modulus is asymptotically between $\frac{a^k}{kn}$ and $\frac{a^k}{n}$, $a:=r^n$. I don't think that's fast enough shrinking to guarantee an irrational limit.

Comment: In that case, I think a proof would have to tackle the harder problem of proving that the infinite sum of the rational numbers invariably converges to an irrational. I'm keeping my day job! :-)

Comment: Well consider all the other series of rational numbers for which convergence to a rational/irrational is not known.  E.g. $\pi + e$ can be written as a series of rationals...

Comment: True. $\Sigma n^{-2} = \pi^2/6$ also comes to mind, and it would be absolutely no surprise if it did (and given Wiles' proof, actually does) converge to an irrational, but I wouldn't even know how to start trying to prove that!

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar Did you try to check the proof ?

Comment: Which Proof?! I don't believe I actually offered one!

Comment: So as you see the binomial series for $(1+t)^{1/n}$ doesn't help to find solutions of $r \in \mathbb{Q}^*, (1+r^n)^{1/n} \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ ie. solutions to the Fermat equation $x^n = y^n+z^n, (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Q}^*$. The historical approach was instead to use $1+t^n  = \prod_{l=1}^n (t-e^{(2l+1) i \pi / n})$ which leads to a factorization problem in the number field $\mathbb{Q}[e^{i \pi /n}]$. It is because its ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i \pi /n}]$ lacks of unique factorization that the FLT is so hard.

Comment: Physicists seem to have a talent for making math errors that cancel out to give the right answer. On this site, a Q asked for help in understanding a paper by Einstein (circa 1910). In fact there was a significant math error, and a  little later, another, that cancelled the effects of the 1st error. And  this was in a paper that passed peer-review by other physicists (in order to be published).

Comment: Hans Ohanian has an interesting book out on all of Einstein's mistakes.

Comment: Funny. Wiles' thm. asserts that your series expansion $(1+r^n)^{-\frac 1n}$ cannot converge in $\mathbf R$ to a rational. Whereas it always converges in the p-adic field $\mathbf Q_p$ for $r$ p-adically small, and this is used to show that **no** "elementary"  proof (in a precise sense) of  FLT can work, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590336